# Why is save sending an error on the second time it's used

Tags: xpages

I have an order form with a library that calculates pricing.  document1 is the main customer data source and docLineItem is the item that is ordered data source.  When the user enters an item to add to the order, the code creates the item record and updates the main document1 record with the totals for the order (subtotal, extended totals...).  If I enter a order and enter the customer and enter the first item, it saves correctly.  When I enter the second item, the code throws an error, (Exception occurred calling method NotesXspDocument.save() null), on the document1 save.  Why is it doing this?

```
    docLineItem.replaceItemValue("ItemPrice", Number(vQtyPrice));
    docLineItem.replaceItemValue("ItemExtPrice", Number(vExtPrice));
    docLineItem.replaceItemValue("IncenInd", viewScope.vsIncenInd);
    docLineItem.replaceItemValue("SplitInd", viewScope.vsSplitInd);
    docLineItem.save(true);

    document1.replaceItemValue("OrderSubTot", Math.round((vSubTot * 100) / 100));
    document1.replaceItemValue("OrderIncenTot", Math.round((vIncenTot * 100) / 100));
    document1.replaceItemValue("OrderTDTot", Math.round((vTDTot * 100) / 100));
    document1.replaceItemValue("OrderGTot", Math.round((vGTot * 100) / 100));
    document1.save();
```

Stack Trace:

```
    javax.faces.FacesException: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:102)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:228)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:126)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1535)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:228)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=327, col=19: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesXspDocument.save()
null
com.ibm.xsp.script.WrapperDominoEx$fct_DominoDocument.call(WrapperDominoEx.java:527)
com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTDebug.interpret(ASTDebug.java:148)
com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171)
com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTDebug.interpret(ASTDebug.java:148)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:362)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1535)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:228)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
NotesException: Note delete failed
lotus.domino.local.Document.Nsave(Native Method)
lotus.domino.local.Document.save(Unknown Source)
lotus.domino.local.Document.save(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.save(DominoDocument.java:1192)
com.ibm.xsp.script.WrapperDominoEx$fct_DominoDocument.call(WrapperDominoEx.java:505)
com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTDebug.interpret(ASTDebug.java:148)
com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171)
com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTDebug.interpret(ASTDebug.java:148)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:362)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1535)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:228)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

Comment: Please show us the rest of the stack trace from the exception. It's available on the server in the data/IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder. If you can not get to the XPages log files on the server directly, then use XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF to get easy access to the log files from a browser.

Comment: I'm not using a server because we haven't figured out how to configure it yet for a user to VPN in through the firewall and then access the Notes DB.  But here is the trace from the error page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite intriguing one.
According to [this post](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/0/7fff4b9ecbd4fbf78525748600542ce6?OpenDocument), there is a chance you fill some item with null Vector. Confirmed [here](http://in-mood.blogspot.sk/2013/03/frule-notesexception-note-delete-failed.html).

Googled by the tiny detail from your stacktrace - `NotesException: Note delete failed`

Answer (score 0):

I often find that changes to the document "behind" the XSPDocument cause anything using it as a handle to throw a null. It acts as if the variable no longer has a connection to the document behind it. In some of my testing, it will return a NotesID or UNID of the background document, but the XSPDocument will still error with a null.

When I have cases like this, I store the NoteID or UNID in a variable and create a new instance to save.

I'm not sure that is the most efficient method (in fact, I'm sure it's not), but it works until I can determine why the XSPDocument appears to lose it's connection (which I've not found yet). I'd love to see a better method.

Comment: In case this helps, within the script, at the docLineItem.save line, if I type a new line starting with docLineItem. Notes will give me a drop down of what methods are available.  If I do the same thing with document1. it doesn't give me the drop down.  Why is that?  I'm passing document1 as an attribute to the script but all the replaceItemValue lines work, just not the save.

Comment: Brian, it looks like I found the reason.  I was setting a field in the document1 record as null.  Null and "" are different in javascript and sometimes it does one and sometimes the other.  Haven't figured that out yet but I think that was the case.